# findViewById is not defined by Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-pageradapter

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = 
          (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_city);
```

Gives me an error

> The method findViewById is undefined for the type CityFragment.

with:

```
public class CityFragment extends Fragment {

    public CityFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.city,
                    container, false);

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = 
                (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_city);

        autoCompView.setAdapter(
                       new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item)
                );

    return rootView;
    }
}
```

I basically just copied the code from https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android

Any ideas why I get the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because indeed `Fragment` does not have such method `findViewById()`. 
Instead, you should use the `rootView` to access it.

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = 
                (AutoCompleteTextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_city);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change with :

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = 
                (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_city);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = 
          (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_city);
```

to:

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = 
                (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_city);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here rootView is the parent for AutoCompleteTextView. So change it with:

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = 
                (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_city);
```